# How do I create multiple backup jobs using DejaDup backup service?

Tags: 11.10, backup, deja-dup

I'd like to have different backup jobs scheduled at different times and frequencies (for instance, backup my Documents folder daily, but my music folder only on weekends), or backup daily to my local disk, and weekly to my remote server.  I can see only how to set up a single backup job for a specified set of folders to a specified destination in DejaDup.

If there's no way to do this in DejaDup backup utility at the moment, what is my best alternative solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Deja Dup cannot do that at the moment, you are right.  And it currently doesn't plan to (the [feature request bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/324631) is marked Won't Fix).

I've heard good things about [Back In Time](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/backintime-gnome/), but haven't tried it myself.

Comment: The second link is broken.

Answer (score 4):

Open deja-dup-preferences from terminal as a different user.

```
su -
```

or

```
su backupuser
deja-dup-preferences
```

Make the required source, destination and other settings.
In Startup Applications Preferences of you general user, add below command to autobackup when you login to your general user.

```
sudo -u backupuser -s deja-dup --backup
```

Comment: Yap, that's the way i guess to do. But, as someone mention, you can direcly use duplicity. Look `duplicity --help`. I don' really want to create backup users, but make the process so easy.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is possible to do this in Deja Dup - but only as a manual job, i.e. you have to change the properties for different locations.
I know it has been heavily suggested to the Deja Dup project to include the possibility for different profiles but I am not aware of concrete plans to do so. Unfortunately.

Comment: What do you mean by "manual job" – running duplicity?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at backupninja.  It's not graphical, but it provides a relatively simple format for scheduling backup jobs of various sorts, including duplicity.